# Checking a URL for the existence of misspelled brand name

Tags: python, optimization

I have a URL, which may or may not have a misspelled brand name in it. Assume that the typo is one of the brand's many permutations. I want to check for its existence. I wrote the following code, though the complexity is quite...high.

```
import re
from itertools import permutations
url = "http://www.amazno.com/"
brands = [...]
# ^ this is a Set of 25,000 brand names in lowercase, retrieved from Alexa.
# it has "google" and "amazon" in it, for example.

for brand in brands:
    # get all permutations of this brand
    perms_list = ["".join(p) for p in permutations(brand)]

    # remove duplicates by typecasting into a Set
    perms = set(perms_list)

    for perm in perms:
        # search the URL for the permutation
        m = re.search(perm, url)
        if m:
            return 1
return 0
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search check out this page, pay attention that this kind of search works only if your set is ordered

Comment: @Cristian Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out.

Comment: Do you really mean to consider any permutation a typo? For example does **zonama** count as a typo for **amazon**?

Comment: “the complexity is quite”… factorial is the word you were looking for. But no, @Cristian's tip will not work. By the time you get there, the damage is already done, you have already generated n! permutations of each brand (for a 20-char brand, that's about 2000000000000000000 permutations). What you probably want is extract possible words from the url (splitting on symbols for instance), then compute the Levenshtein distance to the brand's name. That's O(n·m).

Comment: @Leon Yes, like **paypla** is a typo of **paypal**. I'm checking for signs that a URL is phishy. I understand **paypa1** is also a typo, but I'm leaving that for the future.

Comment: Finding the Levenshtein edit distance of the word from the word that you are trying to look for might be useful. If you don't want to go implement this by yourself then you can checkout this pip package which can help. https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy